# Add Thumbnail Support in Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a theme where I need to add Thumbnails for the Category

I have tried this in the theme function.php

```
function spencer_cat_support(){
    add_theme_support('category-thumbnails');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'spencer_cat_support');
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is any support in wordpress to add thumbnail to taxonomies like this it is only available for post types and custom post types. You can either write some code to add image support to category or use some external plugin based on which you prefer.
If you prefer writing your own code check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/add-custom-field-to-category
If you prefer external plugin check this:https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/